# Get type of arguments received as input from a file

Tags: java, file, reflection

I have a text file that I pass as an argument to my program. The file contains class names and arguments that I should instantiate:

```
Home:
SmartMeter:30,false
```

I want to create the instances, using reflection but I can't figure out how to get the actual type of the arguments I am getting from the file. After I get this I want to compare them to the parameter types of all the constructors for this class and pick the right one. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    String[] classNameAndParameters;
    String[] parameters;

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        classNameAndParameters = scan.nextLine().split(":");
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(classNameAndParameters[0]);

        // i check for the length too because it throws arrayoutofbounds exception
        if (classNameAndParameters.length > 1 && classNameAndParameters[1] != null) {
            parameters = classNameAndParameters[1].split(",");


            // get all constructors for the created class
            Constructor<?>[] constructors = c.getDeclaredConstructors(); 

            for(int i = 0; i < constructors.length; i++) {
                Constructor<?> ct = constructors[i];
                Class<?> pvec[] = ct.getParameterTypes();

                for (int j = 0; j < pvec.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println("param #" + j + " " + pvec[j]);
                }
            }
            //i should match the parameter types of the file with the parameters of the available constructors


            //Object object = consa.newInstance();
        } else {
            // default case when the constructor takes no arguments
            Constructor<?> consa = c.getConstructor(); 
            Object object = consa.newInstance();
        }
    }

    scan.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify the argument type in the text file otherwise it is impossible for Java to solve the ambiguity of some of the arguments in the runtime.

For example if you have class Book:

```
public class Book {
  public Book() {
  }

  public Book(Integer id, String name) {
  }

  public Book(String idx, String name) {
  } 
}
```

And you supplied *Book: 30, Hunger Games*

How would the code knows which Constructor to pick since 30 is a legit integer and also legit String?

**Assuming** none of your constructors are ambiguous, here's how to do it:

```
String args[] = {"this is id", "this is name"};

Arrays.asList(Book.class.getConstructors()).stream()
    .filter(c -> c.getParameterCount() == args.length).forEach(c -> {
      if (IntStream.range(0, c.getParameterCount()).allMatch(i -> {
        return Arrays.asList(c.getParameterTypes()[i].getDeclaredMethods()).stream()
            .filter(m -> m.getName().equals("valueOf")).anyMatch(m -> {
              try {
                m.invoke(null, args[i]);
                return true;
              } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
              }
            });
      }))
        System.out.println("Matching Constructor: " + c);
    });
```

Comment: When I replace the args array which you compare with the parameter count of the constructor, I get an error - Local variable parameters defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final.

Comment: yes, as per Java Spec, lambda requires that: "a lambda expression can only access local variables and parameters of the enclosing block that are final or effectively final". Sorry but I'm not too sure what you mean, because parameterCount() is an integer and args is a string array

Comment: I mean parameters.length

Comment: not too sure what you mean still, but my wild guess is that you need to declare final String[] parameters, I hope that's the right guess